# How to combine confidence intervals of a regression when calculating a mean of estimated value

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, estimation

I am facing the following problem: I have a regression similar to the following:

```r
fit <- lm(I(hp > 100) ~ cyl + wt + disp + am,data = mtcars)
```

The idea is more or less to estimate the probability of having hp > 100.
I then calculate the mean estimation for each category of `am`:

```r
tapply(predict(fit),mtcars$am,mean)

        0         1 
0.8421053 0.5384615
```

This works for me.
Now I would like to have confidence intervals for these estimates. I can do

```r
predict(fit,interval ="confidence" )

         fit         lwr       upr
1  0.7848704  0.58406685 0.9856739
2  0.8131518  0.58796047 1.0383431
3  0.2948876  0.10013362 0.4896416
4  0.5771351  0.38357191 0.7706984
5  0.9762073  0.72139354 1.2310211
6  0.6588185  0.50067156 0.8169655
7  0.9906253  0.76233687 1.2189137
8  0.2156066 -0.04845223 0.4796655
9  0.2209163 -0.04090334 0.4827359
10 0.7514166  0.50829030 0.9945429
11 0.7514166  0.50829030 0.9945429
12 1.1851648  0.92950067 1.4408290
13 1.1474563  0.92047532 1.3744373
14 1.1530017  0.92392416 1.3820792
15 0.9919425  0.66900143 1.3148836
.
.
.
```

And I get the confidence of each estimation. How can I combine these confidence interval to get the confidence interval of the mean ?

---

## Edits

Isabella Ghement pointed out that I should use `glm` instead of `lm` for binary variable.

I actually used `lm` because for the calculation I want to perform, both `lm` and `glm` are equivalent (I am not interested in individual estimation, but on the average probability on two subgroups):

```r
model <- glm(I(hp > 100) ~ cyl + wt + disp + am, data = mtcars,
              family = binomial(link="logit"))
tapply(predict(model, type = "response"),mtcars$am,mean)

        0         1 
0.8421053 0.5384615
```

But `predict(model, type = "response",interval = "confidence")`  does not give the confidence interval of individual estimation, where it does for `lm`.

My question is to know if there is a way of calculating the CI of the two values `0.8421053` for `am = 0` and `0.5384615` for `am = 1` from the individual CI given by `predict(fit,interval ="confidence" )`, to avoid computer intensive calculation such as bootstraping.

Comment: If you want a 95% CI for the `am` coefficient (not the "mean"), does `confint(fit)` answer your question? Otherwise, you may have to define appropriate contrasts using, e.g., the  `rms` or `effects` packages.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually want the CI for the calculated mean of the `fit` column. So my question is: how to I calculate that absed on the `lwr` and `upr` columns ?

Comment: Do you mean you are interested in the 95% CI for `tapply(predict(fit),mtcars$am,mean)`, when, e.g., `am = 1`?

Comment: I want to compute the 95% CI for the two values given by `tapply(predict(fit),mtcars$am,mean)`: 0.8421053 for `am = 0` and 0.5384615 for `am =1`. I was wondering if there was a way to do so from the individual CI given by predict, I am trying to avoid bootstraping

Comment: Do you mean this? `library(rms); d <- datadist(mtcars); options(datadist = "d"); m <- lrm(I(hp > 100) ~ cyl + wt + disp + am, data = mtcars, x = TRUE); Predict(m, am = 0:1)`. (You can fix the other predictors to whichever values you like, and even perform joint estimation using `conf.type="simultaneous"`.)

Answer (score 1):

Your response variable is binary - fitting a *linear regression model*, lm(), to a binary variable is not the best thing you can do. As you can see from your own response, a linear regression model can produce "probabilities" whose values are non-sensical (e.g., > 1).  By definition, probabilities can only take values between 0 and 1.

Why not use a more appropriate model for your data, namely a *binary logistic regression model*? In R, you would fit this model with:

```
model <- glm(I(hp > 100) ~ cyl + wt + disp + am, data = mtcars,
    family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

The R command summary(model) will summarize the glm() model fit, showing how the log odds that hp > 100 depend on the values of the predictor variables included in the model.

The glm() model can be used as a basis for predicting the probability that hp > 100 as a function of the cyl, weight, disp and am values for the cars represented in your data:

```
prob <- predict(model, type = "response") 

prob
```

Now, let's say you want to focus only on those cars with am = 0 represented in your data; for these cars, you can estimate the "average" probability that they have hp > 100.  This involves subsetting prob, as computed above, so that it includes only probabilities for which am = 0, and then computing the average of the subsetted probabilities (across the combinations of cyl, weight and displ values represented in that subset).

You can get a 95% confidence interval for the "average" probability using bootstrapping. Essentially, repeat the subsetting process described above for each of B = 999 (say) bootstrap samples and save your "average" probability for each such sample. Then order the bootstrap "average" probabilities from smallest to largest and report the appropriate quantiles of their distribution as the endpoints of your confidence interval.

Comment: (+1) Oh, well done, I missed the fact that the response variable was binary! You may want to add a note about the `effects` package (or other related ones) for computing the marginal effect of `am`.

Comment: Thank you, @chl!  I’m not sure whether the effects package is helpful here, as it still requires the use of specific values for the other predictors in the model. For this reason, I suggested bootstrapping.

Comment: Thank you. You are right `glm` is better, but it does not really change my problem, that was getting the 95% CI. As far as I understand, you are proposing bootstraping. I was wondering if there was a more direct way, i.e. a possible calculation from the individual CI of each estimation.

Comment: That's exactly my problem: marginal effect would require specific values of the other predictors, and the proportion of the predictors are specific to my population. I was trying to avoid bootstraping

Comment: @chl I eddited my question to be more specific

Comment: `weight` should be `wt` in your example (I cannot edit less than 6 characters)

Comment: You haven’t given us the coordinates of your real problem - just a surrogate example. On that basis, for the mtcars dataset, bootstrapping will be really fast - just write a function called getProbs() which computes the “average” probability for a bootstrap sample when am is set to a specific value and feed it to the *boot()* function in the **boot** package. For an example of how you can use the *boot()* function, see http://dwoll.de/rexrepos/posts/resamplingBootALM.html. If you use glm(), I doubt there is an alternative to bootstrapping.

Comment: Personally, I would not use lm() in this setting. Averaging over non-sensical probabilities like 1.2, etc., is bound to produce a non-sensical “average” probability.  But you know more about your real data (not mtcars!), so which model to use is your decision. We don’t know anything about your real data, so we cannot comment here on whether using equal weights in the computation of the “average” probability is adequate.

Comment: That’s all I had to say - I will defer to @chl for further insights.